# How to put html tags in sinatra strings

Tags: html, ruby, sinatra

I just started Sinatra and try to render the name with `h1` html tag but its not working. Although the string is coming without html tag but it is also not rendering the html tag as desired let me know how do I handle it in `Sinatra`

My code -

```
get '/nesh' do
    name = "Swapnesh"
    "Hello <h1> #{name} </h1> Sinha"
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string you're returning from the `get '/nesh'` block is exactly what will be returned in the HTTP request, which is why it is not wrapped in `<html>...</html>` tags. If you want there to be surrounding tags such as `<html>`, `<body>`, etc., then you should create a Sinatra [view](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Views%20/%20Templates) template, and pass your view information (such as `name`) into the view renderer.

A complete example might look like this:

**app.rb**:

```
set :views, settings.root + '/templates'

get '/nesh' do
  name = "Swapnesh"
  erb :hello, :locals => {:name => name}
end
```

**templates/layout.erb**:

```
<html>
<body>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
```

**templates/hello.rb**:

```
<h1>Hello <%= name %> Sinha</h1>
```

Notice I also used a Sinatra [layout](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Named%20Templates), which is a base template for all rendered actions (unless opted-out).

Finally, you could implement it all in one file using [named templates](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Named%20Templates):

```
template :layout do
  <<-EOF
<html>
<body>
  <%= yield %>
</body>
</html>
EOF
end

template :hello do
  "<h1>Hello <%= name %> Sinha</h1>"
end

get '/nesh' do
  name = "Swapnesh"
  erb :hello, :locals => {:name => name}
end
```

Comment: thx for the info..however thr is also a way to do it in a single file

Comment: Are you _asking_ whether there is a way to do it in a single file?

Comment: I just posted an answer plz chk and tell if this is the correct way of doing it or not..im in the initial stage of Sinatra learning

Comment: If you're trying to have it all in one file, I would use [named templates](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Named%20Templates). See the end of my latest edited answer for an example.

Comment: just curious ..why BlaineOmega code fails altough it look ok at first instace

Comment: Where is the `resultPage.erb` template located? By default, it would need to be within a `views/` subdirectory.

Comment: Excellent point..I have not created that folder so I believe this is what causing all trouble..thanks a lot man :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `HTML` and Sinatra, you should use `erb`, or something similar to display the `HTML`.

Example your code:

```
get '/nesh' do
    name = "Swapnesh"
    erb :resultPage, :locals => {:name => name}
end
```

Example resultPage.erb:

```
<p> Hello <h1> <%=#{name}%> </h1> Sinha</p>
```

Comment: See the [available template languages](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Available%20Template%20Languages).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is the correct way or not but i tried this way and it works..

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/nesh' do
    @name = "Swapnesh"
    erb :test
end

__END__
@@test
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Test Sinatra pass</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<p> Hello <h1> <%= @name %> </h1> Sinha</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is one way to do it (you can do whatever you like, basically),  but it's not _idiomatic_. Since most of the time you'll want the same layout (head, meta, doctype etc) for different routes it makes sense to make a layout file and `yield` the results of a view into it.

Comment: @iain yes u r right..as i am on the primary level of Sinatra learning so I want to cover as much ground I can :)